# Why UDP and TCP use port number but not PID to locate the destination?

Tags: networking, tcp

As above.

Maybe port number is more reliable as process can be terminated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processes are not a network concept. It's not clear that the communicating parties even have a notion of processes.

Also, a process can have many connections.